# Parse JSON file in Java: getJSONObject(int) is undefined

Tags: java, arrays, json

I`m trying to fetch some values fron a JSON file using:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\myfile.json"));
JSONArray array= new JSONArray();
array.add(obj);
```

If I run:    `System.out.println(array);`   , the output is

```
[{"flowrate":{"mod":0,"value":110},"command":{"cancel":0,"start":0}}]
```

, which is my json file.
My problem is how to get value from a specific field, let's say the value of `"comand":"cancel"`.

I've tried `JSONObject myitem = array.getJSONObject(1).getJSONObject("cancel");` with no success (error: `getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray`).

I mention that I'm using the json-simple toolkit.

Comment: I tried validating the JSON you're using at https://jsonlint.com/ and it says it's not valid. Is "["flowrate":{"mod":0,"value":110},"command":{"cancel":0,"start":0}] " the JSON that's in your myfile.json?

Comment: you are right. My mistake that i kind of wrote it from memory. it was missing   { } final enclosure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching, I discovered that there is big difference between { } and [ ], therefore differnent methodes to parse them:

[image]

In my case:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\myfile.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) json;
JSONObject command= (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("command");
System.out.println("command: " + command);
long cancel= (Long) command.get("cancel");
System.out.println("cancel: " + cancel);
```

Here you'll find the [best example for nested json objects](http://www.websparrow.org/java/how-to-parse-nested-json-object-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I also could not validate your JSON. I made an assumption that you wanted to create an array of two objects (flowrate and command) and fixed the JSON:

```
    String value = "[{\"flowrate\":{\"mod\":0,\"value\":110}},{\"command\":{\"cancel\":0,\"start\":0}}]";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(value);
    JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) array.get(1);
    System.out.println(jo.get("command"));
```

which gives the following output:

```
{"cancel":0,"start":0}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: your example works, but i still can't understand why the same stupid json refuses to work when it is parsed from file. man, it gets frustrating :))